# Strange predictions from GAMs

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

I am fitting a GAM to data of capture success in trapping sites using the `mgcv` package in R. The independent variables are proportions of land cover types. Here are:

- the output of my model:

> summary(mod)

```
Family: Gamma 
Link function: log 

Formula:
capt_succ ~ s(p_urban, k = -1, bs = "cs") + 
    s(p_crop, k = -1, bs = "cs") + s(p_forest, k = -1, 
    bs = "cs") + s(p_wetland, k = -1, bs = "cs") + s(p_grassland, 
    k = -1, bs = "cs")

Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  2.55181    0.01436   177.7   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                  edf        Ref.df    F        p-value    
s(p_urban)        8.256      9         21.508   6.70e-16 ***
s(p_crop)         7.077      9         8.855    3.22e-07 ***
s(p_forest)       8.523      9         20.536   3.18e-15 ***
s(p_wetland)      8.068      9         5.782    0.000124 ***
s(p_grassland)    8.195      9         8.585    1.12e-06 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.907   Deviance explained = 97.1%
GCV = 0.040875  Scale est. = 0.011957  n = 58
```

- the diagnostics for my model:

> gam.check(modA2R)

```
Method: GCV   Optimizer: outer newton
full convergence after 10 iterations.
Gradient range [-1.66113e-10,5.218356e-11]
(score 0.04087502 & scale 0.01195669).
Hessian positive definite, eigenvalue range [0.001008947,0.002814858].
Model rank =  46 / 46 

Basis dimension (k) checking results. Low p-value (k-index<1) may
indicate that k is too low, especially if edf is close to k'.

               k'    edf     k-index p-value
s(p_urban)     9.000 8.256   1.007    0.54
s(p_crop)      9.000 7.077   1.345    1.00
s(p_forest)    9.000 8.523   0.988    0.42
s(p_wetland)   9.000 8.068   1.148    0.82
s(p_grassland) 9.000 8.195   1.134    0.86
```

The residual plots were acceptable.

Next, I used this model to do predictions of capture success over large areas from:

```
pred <- predict(mod, newdata = test, se.fit=TRUE, type="response", na.action=na.pass)
> summary(pred$fit)
     Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max.       
   0.0002    6.2700   14.7600   56.8400   38.8400 2363.0000
```

Why do I obtain high predicted values for capture success (i.e., max = 2363) when capture success in the original data (i.e., data used for the GAM) ranged from 6 to 28 ?

Is my GAM oversmoothing ?

**Update**

I logit-transformed the proportion of anthropogenic areas and wetlands for stabilizing the variance. So, the output of the GAM includes the logit-transformation.

```
function(p) { log(p/(1-p)) }
```

To built the GAM, I used proportions of land cover types which were calculated within trapping sites (min size = 25km²). To do predictions from the GAM, I used proportions of land cover types which were calculated within grid cells of 2km x 2km.

Comment: Have you checked where the predictor values that lead to these high values are in your model space? Are you possibly extrapolating? I'm also not sure if it might be a problem that your predictors have a dependency structure you haven't accounted for. Presumably, the proportions sum to one? Possibly you should leave out one of the predictors?

Comment: Thank you very much Roland for your answer. I noted that the high values were often present in grid cells where the proportion of wetlands and anthropogenic areas are near to zero or the proportion of water bodies (not included in the model) is equal to 1. I have deleted the proportion of wetlands in the model and the max value for capture success was 160 instead 2363. This is more consistent but why does the proportion of wetlands induce high prediction values? I checked the predictions with the original data (data used to build the GAM) and these predictions were well ranged from 6 to 28